# Update metadata of MOSS document library item using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2007, wss

Is it possible to update metadata of an item in SharePoint 2007 document library using powershell?

I'd like to execute a CAML query and then change && update every item in the results list. My goal is to write a single throwaway script instead of writing a console app in VS. Can anyone point me towards a way of doing this?

Thanks,
josko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm normally able to do anything in sharepoint 2010 just using Powershell and:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Sharepoint")
```

But never tried in Sharepoint 2007. However I think you won't have any problem, since it seems Sharepoint Services 3.0 supports the assembly as well, along with [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes that will work, Powershell can load arbitrary assemblies. You might also look at IronPython for writing simple little scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can update document library item using powershell.
please refer site : 
http://www.powershell.nu/2009/09/08/moss-2007-script-collection/ 

Refer these examples given here.